# Smart switch not working with correct setting

Tags: smart-switch

My house built just this year and it supposed to have neutral wires in the switch box.
So, I bought kasa smart switch.
Before connect supply-in wire, i used VOL detector to make sure that's the only one line makes the detector beeps.

After connecting all the wires... the switch doesn't have any signal.
Any idea?

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B079775ZZQ?ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079775ZZQ)

Comment: What does "no signal" mean?  Does it operate the lights?  Does the switch have any indicator LEDs that show when it's getting power?  Also, what's with the tiny little pigtails for the load and supply wires?

Answer (score 5):

I see a whole bunch of white in the back. I suspect you pulled one white neutral at random from a bunch and connected that to the switch. **All neutrals need to stay together** - i.e., in one wire nut or in two with a connecting wire.

Comment: Yep - and now there's also something else nearby which doesn't work anymore because its neutral isn't connected to that bundle like it was before.